# Makefile error, make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, mingw-w64

i am very new in build systems and i am trying to build c++ file with mingw compiler and makefile on windows.

i installed mingw and added it to PATH. My code as follows

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World !!!! "
    return 0;
}

//Makefile

program:
    g++  main.cpp  -o  program
```

i change my working directory as C:\MyDir which is included my .cpp and Makefile

```
cd C:\\MyDir

C:\\MyDir> make
```

i get the error

> make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop ...

Do you have any idea about this problem, thanks..

Comment: Could you add information about which specific MinGW package you installed? MinGW often contains the program `mingw32-make.exe` rather than `make.exe`.

Comment: Please show the contents of the directory `MyDir`.  Are you sure you didn't name your makefile with an extension like `Makefile.txt` or something like that?  Make clearly cannot find the file named `Makefile` in your directory, so your statement that the directory contains _my .cpp and Makefile_ is not the case.

Comment: Thank you @MadScientist the problem is that Makefile was in txt format, i change the format and solve problem!

Comment: It's not the "format" of the file.  It's just the name of the file.  Glad you got it sorted!